# I Have Need to change products price and currency store wise?

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I have 2 stores for my site one for India and other store for other countries.

i will show price in india in INR and for other countries in DOLLAR.

and product price will be put according us in admin. no need to Currency conversion automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set price per website basis.

I Had create new website, store and store view.

Then you need to go to System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog.

Then in the tab "Price", set price scope to Website instead of global.

Now working fine i set different price for each website.

Comment: What if I hv created direct store instead of website

Comment: @Divya  As I know Magento default does not support changing product price and currency at the level of store view.